# Error:Unexpected type tag 13996 found. or Enable Multidex for Apps with Over 64K Methods

Tags: java, android, gradle, methods, dependencies

I got the

### **Enable Multidex for Apps with Over 64K Methods**

error. I search it and the solution is here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

When I apply the solution that told by android it self, I get another error :

### **Error:Unexpected type tag 13996 found.**

***What should I do?***

**For more details:**
 Web side: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html
 basically says that add  **multiDexEnabled true** to defaultConfig of **app level build gradle** and add **compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'** to dependencies.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

And according the below article I need to extend my application class from
 **MultiDexApplication** like this

> if you do override the Application class, change it to extend
>   MultiDexApplication (if possible) as follows: public class
>   MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }

```
import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;

import com.engly.learnenglish.app.util.model.VocabularyModel;
import com.onesignal.OneSignal;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

    public class App extends MultiDexApplication {

        private static App instance = null;
        private static List<VocabularyModel> vocabularyModelList;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            instance = this;
            vocabularyModelList = new ArrayList<>();
            OneSignal.startInit(this)
                    .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                    .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                    .init();
        }

        public static App getInstance() {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new App();
            }
            return instance;
        }

        public static List<VocabularyModel> getVocabularyModelList() {
            return vocabularyModelList;
        }

        public static void setVocabularyModelList(List<VocabularyModel> vocabularyModelList) {
            App.vocabularyModelList = vocabularyModelList;
        }
        public static void addVocabularyToList(VocabularyModel vocabularyModel){
            App.vocabularyModelList.add(vocabularyModel);
        }

    }
```

When I apply the solution I get this error

```
Error:Unexpected type tag 13996 found.
```

**This is my project level gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
        //in sake of butter knife
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
ext {
    /*
    App version
     */
    versionCode = 8
    versionName = '2.0.0'


    /*
    SDK version
     */
    buildToolsVersion = '25.0.0'
    compileSdkVersion = 25
    minSdkVersion = 16
    targetSdkVersion = 25

    /*
    Dependency versions
     */
    supportLibVersion = '25.0.0'
    butterknifeVersion = '8.4.0'
    commonsioVersion = '2.5'
    appacheCommonsVersion = '3.4'
    googleGsonVersion = '2.7'
    relexCircleIndicatorVersion = '1.2.2@aar'
    viewpagerTransformsVersion = '1.2.32@aar'
    pageLoaderVersion = '0.0.2'
    topSnackbarVersion = '1.1.1'
    retrofit2Version = '2.0.2'
    picassoVersion = '2.5.2'
    recyclerTabLayoutVersion = '1.1.0'
    okhttpVersion = '2.4.0'

    /*
    Dependencies
     */
    supportLibAppCompat = "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    supportLibDesign = "com.android.support:design:$supportLibVersion"
    supportLibRecyclerView = "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    supportLibPercentLayout = "com.android.support:percent:$supportLibVersion"
    supportLibCardView = "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    butterknife = "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$butterknifeVersion"
    butterknifeApt = "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$butterknifeVersion"
    commonsIo = "commons-io:commons-io:$commonsioVersion"
    appacheCommons = "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:$appacheCommonsVersion"
    googleGson = "com.google.code.gson:gson:$googleGsonVersion"
    relexCircleIndicator = "me.relex:circleindicator:$relexCircleIndicatorVersion"
    picasso = "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:$picassoVersion"
    okhttp = "com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:$okhttpVersion"
    retrofit2 = "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit2Version"
    retrofit2Converter = "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit2Version"
    viewpagerTransforms = "com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms:view-pager-transforms:$viewpagerTransformsVersion"
    pageLoader = "id.arieridwan:pageloader:$pageLoaderVersion"
    topSnackbar = "com.androidadvance:topsnackbar:$topSnackbarVersion"
    recyclerTabLayout = "com.nshmura:recyclertablayout:$recyclerTabLayoutVersion"
}
```

**This is my app level gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin' version '0.8.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "2fe20af9-bdcf-49cd-bbfe-6ffd8f11f8c2",
                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
        applicationId 'com.engly.learnenglish.app'
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode rootProject.ext.versionCode
        versionName rootProject.ext.versionName
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
        generatedDensities = []
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    lintOptions
            {
                checkReleaseBuilds false
                abortOnError false

            }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //support lib
    compile rootProject.ext.supportLibAppCompat
    compile rootProject.ext.supportLibPercentLayout
    compile rootProject.ext.supportLibRecyclerView
    compile rootProject.ext.supportLibCardView
    compile rootProject.ext.supportLibDesign
    //butterknife
    compile rootProject.ext.butterknife
    annotationProcessor rootProject.ext.butterknifeApt
    //commons
    compile rootProject.ext.commonsIo
    compile rootProject.ext.appacheCommons
    //gson
    compile rootProject.ext.googleGson
    //circle indicator
    compile rootProject.ext.relexCircleIndicator
    //piccasso
    compile rootProject.ext.picasso
    //retrofit
    compile rootProject.ext.okhttp
    compile rootProject.ext.retrofit2
    compile rootProject.ext.retrofit2Converter
    //recyclerview tablayout
    compile rootProject.ext.recyclerTabLayout
    //viewpager animation
    compile rootProject.ext.viewpagerTransforms
    //page loader
    compile rootProject.ext.pageLoader
    //top position snackbar
    compile rootProject.ext.topSnackbar
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.0, 3.99.99]'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.michaelye.easydialog:easydialog:1.4'
    compile 'com.hbb20:ccp:1.7.8'
    compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.4.1'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularprogressbar:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.victor:lib:1.0.4'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.1'
    compile 'com.appsee:appsee-android:2.3.3'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Full version gradle error from idea.log**

```
  com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Unexpected type tag 13996 found.
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.ProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(ProjectImportErrorHandler.java:85)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:414)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:158)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:906)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:886)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:218)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:139)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:79)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:45)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:139)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:125)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:388)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:445)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:726)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected type tag 13996 found.
    at org.gradle.internal.serialize.DefaultSerializerRegistry$TaggedTypeSerializer.read(DefaultSerializerRegistry.java:142)
    at org.gradle.internal.serialize.Serializers$StatefulSerializerAdapter$1.read(Serializers.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.receive(SocketConnection.java:79)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection.receive(DaemonClientConnection.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection.receive(DaemonClientConnection.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.monitorBuild(DaemonClient.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.executeBuild(DaemonClient.java:178)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:141)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:92)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:143)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:128)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.run(DefaultConnection.java:208)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerConnection$CancellableActionRunner.run(CancellableConsumerConnection.java:99)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.run(ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:84)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
```

Comment: Have you tried full exit the Android Studio, and kill all process relative to gradle daemon (`ps -eaf | grep "gradle"` to find the gradle process, and `kill <process-id>` to kill it)? If problem still there, maybe you can paste log of Android Studio to help others to location the issue. (click the "Show Log in Finder" when sync failed)

Comment: @Tankery I haven't and I will. Is your suggestion for `Enable Multidex for Apps with Over 64K Methods` error or `Unexpected type tag 13996 found`. error ?

Comment: I do solved `Unexpected type tag 13996 found` by exit Android Studio and kill all the process of gradle, because I've found the error is relative to GradleDaemon from the log of AS. But I don't know if it caused by multidex in my case.

Comment: @Tankery to kill processes did not work for me :( I pasted full version of the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Error:Unexpected type tag 13996 found.
```

The cause is onesignal. When you use `multiDexEnabled true` with onesignal it going to make `Unexpected type tag 13996 found` error.

It should be a bug. After updating `version '0.8.0'` to `version '0.8.1'`, the problem will be fixed.

```
 plugins {
        id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin' version '0.8.1'
    }
```

For more info : https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin/issues/15 and https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/issues/391

**

### BUT MAIN PROBLEM WAS  `Enable Multidex for Apps with Over 64K Methods`

**

You can fix it through this web side info:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

### OR

What I have done is to check all libraries in my `Module:app` level `gradle`in order to find unused resources and libraries. The mean reason of the problem is to use a lot of methods. If your project is not really big, you can not probably write that much methods. In fact, the cause should be libraries that you actively use or that never call any single method from it. You should find the unused libraries or unnecessary libraries that you added. When you clean up your project from this libraries the problem should be fixed. If you can't delete any library, follow this steps:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html